# How to save Mongoid foreign_key as integer or keep the parent model have Integer id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Here is the situation.

```
user embed_one profile
profile belongs_to city
```

I have populated a city table with

```
id as Integer
name as String
```

Now I am doing 
`user.update_attributes(:profile_attributes{:city_id=>"5"})`simulating a browser form submission. Then I check `user.profile` I see that city_id is stored as string. This renders my `user.profile.city` to give nil.

I am wondering what is the right thing to do here. Should I let my city id be string or BSON object? Or should I try to intercept update_attributes to make mongoid store city_id as integer? The reason I am using Integer as id for city is because I thought searching through Integer is faster than searching through string. And also I have state and city tables and I want to match the ids in a predictable manner so I don't want to use BSON randome key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, if you use Mongoid, the right way is to use BSON objects as ids. But if you absolutely need to use integers as city ids, you can simulate belongs_to with code like this

```
class Profile
  def city
    City.where(:id => self.city_id).last
  end

  def city=(new_city)
    self.city_id = new_city.id
  end
end
```

Comment: this looks promising. but may be a lot of methods to add if the problem pertains to many tables and many attributes. Would be nice if I can automatically convert string params to integer if I declare those attributes as integer. Monkey patching to Mongoid, maybe?

Comment: What's the problem with bson objects?

Comment: I am porting City states tables. And I want integer to be id of state so my city refers to the right state. I guess I can use a separate attribute as foreign key then I would not mind bson as id.